# Haskell: read a number (Integer or Floating point)

Tags: parsing, haskell, input, io, typing

I am using this implementation of `maybeRead`:

```
maybeRead :: (Read a) => String -> Maybe a
maybeRead = fmap fst . listToMaybe . filter (null . dropWhile isSpace . snd) . reads
```

and my own `getNum` function which prompts until it gets valid input:

```
getNum :: (Num a, Read a) => String -> IO a
getNum s = do
    putStr s
    input <- fmap maybeRead getLine
    if isNothing input
        then getNum s
        else return $ fromJust input
```

However if I enter `5.2` it treats it as bad input—Why? There is zero occurences of `Int` and `Integer` in my code. I am only using `Num`, since I want to accept any kind of number.

If I call it explicitly as `getNum "Enter a number: " :: IO Double`, then it works. Do I have to do this? Is Haskell's type system just tricking me into thinking I should be able to do this when really it is impossible without full dynamic typing? If so then why does my code even compile; why does it assume integers?

Comment: Small stylistic note: It's better to use pattern matching than `isNothing` and `fromJust`, so the `if` expression can be replaced with `case input of Nothing -> getNum s; Just x -> return x`.

Comment: Thanks, that does look a lot better.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your function will indeed accept `Integer`, `Float`, or any other `Num` instance. However, which type it accepts, and by extension how it parses the `String`, is not determined by the *input it receives*, it's determined by *what type the result should be* based on what you do with it.

Say you use `getNum` and pass the resulting value to something that needs a `Float`; in that case, it will parse a `Float` value. If you pass it to something that needs an `Integer` instead, it will parse that.

As for why it assumes `Integer`, there is a "defaulting" system for ambiguous types [specified in the Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4), and the rules say that an ambiguous type with a `Num` constraint should default to `Integer`.

Comment: Okay, so I guess in my example I would have to add `:: (Fractional a, Read a) => IO a` when I call `getNum` to allow for fractional numbers (and I don't want to explicitly specify float or double).

Comment: Yes, but note that adding a `Fractional` constraint will limit it to accepting *only* instances of `Fractional`, so you wouldn't be able to use it for other types that way. Most of the time in an actual program you'll know a specific type you need, so usually there's no reason to constrain things, except for stuff like testing in GHCi.

Comment: I didn't add it to the actual function, I added that as a type annotation when I use the function. I'm not quite sure I understand what you're saying in the last sentence—aren't typeclass constraints ubiquitous in Haskell code for generalizing functions?

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I misread. Anyway, all I was saying is that adding *extra* constraints or explicit type annotation is rarely necessary in practice, because eventually you'll pass the output of `getNum` to something that expects a particular type, and type inference will handle it from there.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean now. I guess I could actually get rid of the `Num a`, couldn't I, since it should be inferred that I want to read numbers at some point (whether or not I annotate with `Fractional`) and that would actually make the function more general and useful.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You don't actually *need* to constrain it any further than `Read a`.

Comment: I've changed it to that, and I'm also just using `default (Double)` instead of that long type annotation since this is very small module and I think it's more logical that way.